# why std::move behaves like std::copy?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, move-semantics, std

Consider the following piece of code -

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> d {100, 200, 300};
    std::vector<int> l {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    std::move(d.begin(), d.end(), std::inserter(l, l.begin()));

    for (int n : l) std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (int n : d) std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n\n';


    for (int &n : d) n +=5;

    for (int n : l) std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (int n : d) std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Here the original `std::vector l` was inserted with contents of `std::vector d` after the move operation. I know that all standard library objects that have been moved from are placed in a valid but unspecified state, however, I was curious to move further and inspect the values. The value of `std::vector d` still remained same after the move operation which could be justified as if *both are referring to same data location*? Again, when I tried to modify those values, the change is not reflected back in the new `std::vector l` container.

Here's the output -

> ```
> 100 200 300 1 2 3 4 5 
> 100 200 300 
>
> 100 200 300 1 2 3 4 5 
> 105 205 305
> ```

It seems the values are copied from source container to destination container and the source container gets to keep originals. Doesn't this sound like a `std::copy` operation?

Comment: From that answer: std::move moves the elements **if possible**, and copies otherwise.

Comment: How do you move an integer, other than by copying it?

Comment: Try a type with different behavior for moving versus copying.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For plain old data, moving and copying are identical. There's no way to move ordinary data other than by copying. Things are different if, for example, you have ownership of some other object that can be transferred without copying it (like `std::string` or `std::shared_ptr` has). But for `int`, that doesn't apply.